# Concatenating columns with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling with a small problem. I have a table as follows

```
name id
a    1
b    1
c    2
d    2
e    3
f    4
```

I need output as follows.

```
a-b  1
c-d  2
e    3
f    4
```

I need to get the concatenated name for a given `ID`.I tried using concat function but i ended up empty handed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '-') AS name 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Yeah,GROUP_CONCAT is one of Mysql`s gems.

Comment: Does it support for sql as well?

Comment: @user2037445 No,you have to do some acrobatics for that. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT group_concat(`name` SEPARATOR '-') AS NAMES
     , `id` 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `id`;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94c1/3)